# Is Meatlug female or male?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How To Train Your Dragon* Fishleg repeatedly said "good girl" or "she is exhausted!", also "her wing is about to fall off!" in the series "Dragon race to berk" or in the first movie.

So is Meatlug female or male?

Comment: From all those quotes, what makes you think she *isn't* female? Is there anything suggesting that she could be male to begin with?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that Fishleg is wrong about Meatlug's gender?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I've seen the first film, and if I'm thinking of the same character as OP, she *does* look very masculine and androgynous, to the extent I wouldn't have known she was female if she hadn't been referred to using female pronouns.

Comment: Now we're *judging* dragons by appearance? - That's not very PC :)

Comment: @F1Krazy That might be worth adding to the question for more context and motivation then.

Comment: Never mind, I thought the question was about one of the human characters, not one of the dragons.

Answer (score 6):

## She's female

As we find out in [*Gift of the Night Fury*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2065968/), she lays eggs (about the 12m mark) and these hatch into baby dragons

> In the events of the movie short, Gift of the Night Fury, Meatlug attempts to leave mysteriously like all the other dragons on Berk during Snoggletog. Fishlegs realizes that she is not a male as previously assumed, as she lays eggs! One of these eggs is the individual known in the game, Dragons: Rise of Berk, as "Meatlug's Offspring", though Meatlug laid several eggs that hatch on Snoggletog.
>
> <sup>[**Wikia**](http://howtotrainyourdragon.wikia.com/wiki/Meatlug%27s_Offspring)</sup>